How can I get MS-MPI to connect with a GMKtec running Windows 11 from my computer?
I am entirely new with MPI and MS-MPI, so this will be the utmost basic of questions that will hopefully have a simple answer.
I am trying to run a Python script that incorporates mpi4py to distribute part of the workload of a function where half is done on my computer and the other is done on the GMKtec. Both have Windows (my computer has Windows 10 and the GMKtec has Windows 11), both have MS-MPI, and both have all required Python libraries in order to run the script.
I am able to ping the GMK from my computer and the GMK and ping my computer, so they are successfully connected. The public network firewall is also deactivated for now on both machines, as the Ethernet connection between the two devices is listed as a public network.
However, when I attempt to run the script using mpiexec, I get an Error 5: Access Denied when it tries to connect to the GMK. Below is the smpd debug output on my computer (no messages other than smpd initialization are printed on the GMK smpd Powershell window even when running smpd -d 3):
[-1:34832] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client. 
[-1:34832] version check complete, using PMP version 4. 
[-1:34832] create manager process (using smpd daemon credentials) 
[-1:34832] Launching smpd as 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\smpd.exe "C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin\smpd.exe" -p 8677 -d 11 -mgr 700 "job"' 
[-1:34832] smpd reading the port string from the manager 
[-1:36720] Launching smpd manager instance. 
[-1:36720] created set for manager listener 368 
[-1:36720] smpd manager listening on port 50626 
[-1:34832] closing the pipe to the manager 
[-1:36720] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client. 
[-1:36720] Authorization completed. 
[-1:36720] version check complete, using PMP version 4. 
[-1:36720] Received session header from parent id=1, parent=0, level=0 
[01:36720] Connecting back to parent using host COMPUTER_NAME and endpoint 50624 
[01:36720] Authentication completed. Successfully obtained Context for Client. 
[01:36720] Authorization completed. 
[01:36720] handling command SMPD_CONNECT src=0 
[01:36720] now connecting to 192.168.50.101 
[01:36720] 1 -> 2 : returning SMPD_CONTEXT_LEFT_CHILD 
[01:36720] using spn RestrictedKrbHost/192.168.50.101 to contact server 
[01:36720] Previous attempt failed with error 5, trying to authenticate without Kerberos 
[01:36720] ERROR: Failed RpcCliCreateContext error 5 
[01:36720] sending abort command to parent context. 
[01:36720] posting command SMPD_ABORT to parent, src=1, dest=0. 
[01:36720] ERROR: smpd running on COMPUTER_NAME is unable to connect to smpd service on 192.168.50.101:8677 
[01:36720] Handling cmd=SMPD_ABORT result 
[01:36720] cmd=SMPD_ABORT result will be handled locally 
[01:36720] parent terminated unexpectedly - initiating cleaning up. 
[01:36720] no child processes to kill - exiting with error code -1type here

This is the command I ran that resulted in the above: mpiexec -hosts 2 192.168.50.200 1 192.168.50.101 1 hostname
I have also tried using a machinefile alternative to the command, but I get the same output. Note that this also occurs (with the exact same smpd debug messages) when I try to run my Python script using the command as follows: mpiexec -hosts 2 192.168.50.200 1 192.168.50.101 1 python -m mpi4py.run C:\filepath_to_script\script.py
Because of this, I don't think it's a problem with the script as the script runs normally whenever I just use multiple processes on my computer using mpiexec -n 2 python -m mpi4py.run C:\filepath_to_script\script.py. I think it's a problem with permissions, but I don't know which permissions or for which device.
I apologize for this being so basic, but I'm not finding much information on this elsewhere, though I could very well just be bad at researching.
Regardless, any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if more information is needed.
I just really hope the answer isn't that Windows 10 and Windows 11 can't communicate.

This question is similar to: MS MPI Permission errors. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Is MS-MPI the same version on both machines? Also, is SPN the version on both machines? Does it work, if you try to launch MPI from the other machine?
